# Using C, how can I access the same block of memory as another C program?

Tags: c, macos, memory, communication, memory-access

So, I'm on hour one of learning C.  Maybe I'll jump over to C++ tonight.

I'd like to create two command line programs using C that can "talk" to each other.  The first thought that came to mind is to transfer information between the two by writing to and polling files.  However, I figure C provides all the methods I need to directly allocate memory and access it, and that would be much faster and more sensible technique.

Can someone provide an example or advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are asking for is called [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Memory). Unfortunately, shared memory is *not* part of the C language per se, but a feature of the operating system. Since you didn't specify what operating system you are using, I point you to a [Unix SysV shared memory tutorial](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html).

Comment: +1. On Windows shared memory is accomplished by having more than one process map the same file into memory.

Comment: Thanks (to everyone)!  Having the right terms set me on the right path.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're referring to a Shared Memory Segment. You could also use pipes or sockets to communicate between the two processes. Depending on the application, each has its advantage.

Here's a great guide on interprocess communication, which covers the very subject in addition to pipes, sockets.

http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The technology you need to look into is "Shared Memory". 
It is OS-specific, and not in the C Standard Library.

Since you didn't specify an OS, you'll have to do some research on your own.
If you're on Windows, check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a unix environment you can use shmget() and shmat() to create and attach a shared memory segment.  Both process assess the segment via a common integer key.